# Multiple comparison hypothesis testing, combining p-values of subject data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons, spearman-rho

I am thoroughly confused at the correct statistical procedure on a problem I have

7 different physical objects were ranked, subjectively, by 14 people on 6 different attributes (say soft/hard, warm/cold).
For each object for each attribute for each individual, I computed Spearman's rank correlation coefficient between the ranking with 17 quantitative measurable physical parameters of the physical object (such as weight) etc.

My goal is to see which of the 17 quantitative parameters is statistically significantly associated with subjective rankings of attribute X. I have found the p-values for the Spearman's rank correlation coefficients (approximated using student's t distribution). But I have no idea how to combine the data from the 14 subjects to test for significance in a global way.

Do I:

1. Average the Spearman's rank correlation coefficients (Rs) across
   the subjects BEFORE I use it to perform hypothesis testing using
   critical values of Rs. If so, average doesn't seem to be as good as median because of outliers.
2. For each of the 17 attributes, combine the p-values of the associated Spearman's rank correlation coefficients of each individual person using Fisher's method (Though I have reservations about the dependency assumption).
3. Test each p-values from point 2. above and do a majority vote
4. Average the p-values and peform hypothesis testing as normal
5. Average the p-values AND multiply by 2 (Rüschendorf method, see http://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.4966.pdf), and peform hypothesis testing as normal
6. For each of the 17 attributes, use Holm-Bonferroni sequential correction on the 14 subjects. But how many rejection of H0 before I can say this physical attribute is correlated to the subjectively rated attribute X?

Or is there better way?

Also, in here what contributes to multiple testing? Say if I use the simple method per point 1. above, Do I need to apply Bonferroni-type correction for the 6 subjective attributes? the 17 physical properties? Both?

Comment: I wonder if a hierarchical Plackett-Luce model would be useful here.

Comment: @ZoëClark Thanks. Reading into the topic I found something called rank-ordered logit model.  I will look into it and use the 17 physical parameters as covariates.